# Eliminar o remplazar cadena de números en Python

Tags: python

Estoy buscando la forma correcta de eliminar una cadena de números en una url, actualmente tengo este código:

```
image_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repository/master/images/maps/' + data['map'].lower().replace('/levels/','') + '.jpg'
```

este código transforma https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repository/master/images/maps//levels/mapname.jpg en https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repository/master/images/maps/mapname.jpg

pero quiero transformar este tipo de url https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repository/master/images/maps//0123456789/mapname.jpg en https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repository/master/images/maps/mapname.jpg

Comment: Que has intentado?

Comment: No sé muy bien como hacerlo, esto "/" entre los números y el nombre del mapa me fastidia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ese tipo de procesos es conveniente usar expresiones regulares.

En este caso se trata de reconocer secuencias de digitos entre "/". La expresión regular es "/\d+/".

Antes de usar una expresión regular, tienes que compilarla con re.compile. Solo lo haces una vez, luego puedes usar la expresión compilada tantas veces como quieras:

```
import re

exp = re.compile("/\d+/")
```

Las expresiones regulares se pueden usar para reemplazar un texto por otro en forma genérica. Para esto se usa `re.sub()`.

La función `re.sub()` tiene tres parámetros: una expresión regular que se usara para buscar, el cambio a  insertar, y el string donde hay que aplicar las modificaciones. La función retorna el string modificado.,

```
nueva_url = re.sub(exp, "", url)
```

Estas tres líneas son todo lo que necesitas transformar las URL de tu problema.

**Comprobación**

Todo esto se resume en:

```
import re

exp = re.compile("/\d+/")

test=[
    "",
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repository/master/images/maps//levels/mapname.jpg",
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repository/master/images/maps//0123456789/mapname.jpg"
]

for url in test:
    a=re.sub(exp, "", url)
    print(url)
    print(a)
    print()
```

produce

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repository/master/images/maps//levels/mapname.jpg
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repository/master/images/maps//levels/mapname.jpg

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repository/master/images/maps//0123456789/mapname.jpg
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repository/master/images/maps/mapname.jpg
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, la información que has aportado me ha ayudado mucho.